# Lighthouse page score - properly size images and preload

Tags: lazy-loading, preload, google-pagespeed

**Properly Size image penalty:**
I use WP Rocket with lazy load and Revolution Slider with lazy load.  Why do I continue to get penalized with the google lighthouse score "properly size images"?

**Preload penalty:**
I have this in the headers as specified in some of the speed reports (sometimes it penalizes, sometimes it doesn't)  It gives an error that I must use "cross origin" attribute properly.  What goes in the cross origin attribute for the links below?

**My Code:**

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://apartmentskatytexas.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/fonts/revicons/revicons.woff?5510888" as="font" crossorigin="__________">
```

https://apartmentskatytexas.com

Answer (score 0):

Performance score is not based on the checklist, but on the speed of your site. So you are not being penalized. More in my article [How to get a 100% Google Lighthouse score](https://www.usecue.com/blog/how-to-get-a-100-google-lighthouse-score/).